# Python instead of Py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed python successfully (Python 3.10.7), but none of my program gets executed with `python` command, rather I have to use `py` every time.
I've checked that path is present in my environment variables 
Attaching cmd screenshot for the same

[image]

Now for some project requirements I should be able to use `python` instead of `py`. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: On windows you should always use `py -3`. It will always find the correct python version. `python` doesn't normally work and even if you fix your `%PATH` it will break every python update.

Comment: actually I wanted to use ```awslocal``` CLI for a project, but when I type ```awscli``` on command line it gives me above output ```python is not recognized as...```
Do you have anything on that ?
thanks

Comment: `I have installed python successfully (Python 3.10.7), but none of my program gets executed with python command,` ... the second statement means the first statement is not ture, reinstall python from scratch and check the box that says "Add python to PATH" then restart the terminal.

Comment: The thing is ```AWS local``` uses python internally.